# How do I solve inequalities measured in radians?

Tags: inequality

$1- \frac {x^2}{6} < \frac {\sin x}{x} < 1\;$ holds for $x$ when measured in radians, and $|x| < 1$.

Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac {\sin x}{x}\right)$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Use the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)

Comment: The inequality is given.  There is nothing to "solve."  What you should think about.  What will happen to the expression on the left as $x$ approaches $0.$  What does this suggest will happen to the expression in the middle?

Comment: $x$ should be measured in radians, but that doesn't materially contribute to the difficulty of the question

Answer (score 0):

Given $1-\dfrac{x^2}6<\dfrac{\sin x}x<1$ for $x\in(-1,1)$ and $0\in(-1,1)$, since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}6\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to0}1=1,$

it follows from the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red] {1}$.